# Current time on server is 7 minutes different than actual time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, ubuntu, ntp

Does anybody know how this could happen? My server is 7 minutes slower than the real time per google (which matches the real time shown on user devices/phones).

I'm using an **Ubuntu** server on **digital ocean**.

- Current time **on devices** per google (and on mobile phones): 
  [image: google_screenshot]
- Current time **on server** per `ruby` (in irc):

  ```
  Time.zone.now
  => Fri, 27 Jul 2018 09:19:12 CDT -05:00
  ```
- Current time **on server** per `shell` (in irc):

  ```
  `date`
  => "Fri Jul 27 14:19:17 UTC 2018\n"
  ```
- Current time **on server** per shell (directly):

  ```
  $ date
  Fri Jul 27 14:19:28 UTC 2018
  ```

How am I seven minutes off? I've had this server running for 4+ years. I think this happened recently, and it's causing problems syncing between the server and end devices.

**EDIT: @ 9:39AM CDT per Google**:

I just found out about `timedatectl`. It appears my server time is not synced:

```
$ timedatectl
Local time: Fri 2018-07-27 14:32:30 UTC
Universal time: Fri 2018-07-27 14:32:30 UTC
Timezone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: no
DST active: n/a
```

**EDIT: @ 9:47AM CDT per Google**:

I just installed `NTP`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ntp
```

`timedatectl` still shows 7 minutes off, but says *NTP synchronized: yes*:

```
$ timedatectl
Local time: Fri 2018-07-27 14:39:38 UTC
Universal time: Fri 2018-07-27 14:39:38 UTC
Timezone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
RTC in local TZ: no
DST active: n/a
```

**EDIT: @ 9:50AM CDT per Google**:

`timedatectl` now appears correct, but says *NTP synchronized: no* again:

```
$ timedatectl
Local time: Fri 2018-07-27 14:50:12 UTC
Universal time: Fri 2018-07-27 14:50:12 UTC
Timezone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)
NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
RTC in local TZ: no
DST active: n/a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One should always use `NTP` to synchronize time against NTP servers.

Modern Ubuntu recommends [`chrony`](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/NTP.html.en#timeservers) for that purpose. I always use [`ntpd`](https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/ntpd.html).

Comment: I just installed `NTP`. `timedatectl` now says *NTP synchronized: yes*, but the time is still off by 7 minutes... do I just need to wait a few minutes for it to get synced?

Comment: Oh. Honestly, I don’t remember, probably yes. Or read the documentation on how to sync _now_.

Comment: I faced a similar problem(time difference was 8mins), installed ntp and added server domain in /etc/ntp.conf.. time was in sync.